# Initiate different random number generators from the same seed (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I have a base class with its random number generator `rng`. There are several subclasses that are initiated from this base class. I want to initiate a random number generator for each subclass separately. How can I do that without losing randomness?

What I am doing now? (It creates a huge variance between runs of different seeds)

```py
seed = 1
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)
BaseClass(rng)
for subclass in BaseClass.subclasses:
    subclass.rng = rng
```

What do I want to do?

```py
seed = 1
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)
BaseClass(rng)
for subclass in BaseClass.subclasses:
    subclass.rng = rng.initiate_new_random_number_generator()
```

I don't know what `initiate_new_random_number_generator()` should be in order to be still random. Are there any pointers to do this? Ideally, I would like to use PCG64 random number generator because of its low size requirements.

Comment: You could use random numbers generated by "rng" as seeds for the subgenerators.

Comment: With the new BitGenerator package, you can create mulitple generators from the same seed, `rd0 = np.random.default_rng(seed)`  (using PCG64).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Does that not lead to loss of randomness because the seeds are determined by an `rng` itself?